# Passing NOW() as a parameter in an Excel custom function gives a #VALUE! error?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a custom function in Excel which manipulates a date that is passed in as a parameter.  It works fine normally, but if I directly pass in NOW() as the parameter, it results in a #VALUE! error.  However, if I put NOW() in a cell, and pass in that cell as the parameter it works.  I've tried this in both Excel 2007 and Excel 2016 and they both have the same result.

I made a simple function to highlight this (instead of my original function):

[#VALUE! error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7bDI.png)

What's even more confusing is that if I put a Stop in the code and step through it, the value from NOW() *did* actually get passed in and the function runs correctly.  But in the spreadsheet it still shows as a #VALUE! error.

[Value passed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1ejz.png)

Does anyone know why that is happening and a way to make it work?  Like I said, I know I can add a column with =NOW() and use that cell as the parameter, but I'd like to be able to do it without taking that extra step.

Comment: Please do not put the code in picture.  Put the code directly into the Original Post using [edit] so we can copy and paste and test.

Comment: Unlike in VB.NET, not everything is an `Object` in VBA. Do not declare your parameters as `Object` if you intend to pass non-objects too. There is `Variant` for that. But unless you want to actually pass in values of different *meaning*, `ByVal inputThing As Date` will do fine.

Comment: Any reason you're using NOW() instead of TODAY()? NOW includes time and TODAY is just a date.

Comment: @Scott, understood.  I will do that in the future.

Comment: @SGreg, thanks!  Using what you said and what A.S.H. said below I got it.

Comment: @Clouse24, the same problem happened for TODAY().  I sometimes use the actual time in the true function.  Also, it's easier to have more than formation than less as I can always format it off if I don't want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass in a range address, the parameter is passed as a range `Object`, which is then successfully evaluated inside your function . But When you pass it an actual `Date`, the passed parameter is not an object in **VBA**, so the call fails.

Everything will be fine if you change your function prototype into this:

```
Function doStuff(inputThing  as Variant)
```

The `Variant` parameter in VBA is by definition something that can match *anything*, so you can pass it range objects as well as raw value.

Comment: `As Date` will work too. I believe it is preferred unless you actually want to have access to the `Range` object for its other properties.

Comment: @GSerg I was going to add that, but thought that keeping it as variant might provide more flexibility and make the answer shorter..

Comment: @A.S.H, that works, thanks for the help!  When looking up ways to input cells formatted as either dates or text I saw using object as a solution.  I had completely forgotten about variant.